# scrollToPosition() when updating RecyclerView in a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I've made a list which gets items from a Room-database using `LiveData`. This `liveData<List>` is then bound to a `recyclerView`, using a `BindingAdapter`.
The lists adapter is  `listAdapter`, not `RecyclerView.Adapter.

I need help holding onto the scroll-state or somehow returning to the scroll-index I was at before the `recyclerView` reloaded:

```
//In ViewModel
    val movieList = moviesRepository.movies
```

..

```
//in Repo
  val movies: LiveData<List<Movie>> =
    Transformations.map(database.movieDao.getMovies()) {
        it.asDomainModel()
    }
```

Every time the DB updates, the `recyclerView` shoots back up to the top.

And here's the `bindingAdapter` for the `RecyclerView` and the list.

```
@BindingAdapter("listData")
fun bindRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, data: List<Movie>?) {
    val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as MovieListAdapter
    //Log.d("listData binding", "${data}")
    adapter.submitList(data)
}
```

I think I need to  use something like [`recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(la.getItemCount());`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183248/is-there-a-recyclerview-equivalent-to-listviews-transcriptmode-alwaysscroll)
after the update has occured, but I don't know how to automatically call it when the update has occured

[Project Repo](https://github.com/tomkeane07/TheMovieApp/tree/development)

Comment: You can find the easiest answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66026703/12649010).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all don't use `ListAdapter` `RecyclerView` has a more optimized adapter [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter)
2. in your adapter provide a function that overrides the item list **and there is where you notify the data change**
3. Use `smoothScrollToPosition(lastVisiblePosition)` to scroll to the last visible position where `lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()`
4. Update `lastVisiblePosition` before you push new items to the adapter `notifyDatasetChanged()`

**Step 2**

```
fun updateList(newItems:List<Movie>) {
    moviesList.addAll(newItems)
    lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

from your view when you call `adapter.updateList(newItems)` just call `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.lastVisiblePosition)`

Comment: thanks for the reply, any chance you could go into a bit more depth on step 2? Not sure what you mean overriding the 'item list'.
perhaps an example if you have the time

Comment: Thanks, I may implement this solution in the future, but I managed to find a solution which doesn't require me to completely re-jig my Adapter, which would be a bit of a diversion.

Thanks again :)

Comment: OP is using the newer JetPack ListAdapter that is a sublass of RecycleView.Adapter https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter There is no need to replace it. It is the newer recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.
All of the examples I could find were using Activities, not fragments. So all I had to do was pop this into the onCreateView() function in the relevant fragment.kt file.

```
    binding.movieList.layoutManager =
        object : LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), VERTICAL, false) {
            override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State) {
                super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
                val lastVisibleItemPosition = findLastVisibleItemPosition()
                val count = (binding.movieList.adapter as MovieListAdapter).itemCount

                    //speed the scroll up a bit, but make it look smooth at the end
                    binding.movieList.scrollToPosition(count - 5)
                    binding.movieList.smoothScrollToPosition(count)

            }
        }
```

here, the `binding.movieList` is referring to this xml element

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/movie_list"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/load_more_button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:listData="@{viewModel.movieList}"
        tools:listitem="@layout/movie_list_item" />
```

Comment: Your solution will work but it won't be scalable. Better to use the Apis when they exist and don't re-invent the wheel! Happy coding