# scrollToPosition after Android ListAdapter DataSetChanged

Tags: android, listadapter

ListAdapter for RecyclerView has ability to submit a list and it will compute differences between new list and existing list. because of computing diffs asynchronously, it may take a bit of time. I would like to change the current position of recyclerview to last item exactly after submitting list. I didn't find any method to find when diff is computed and also adapter is notified.
Is there any method for notifying when list is notified?

Comment: to upate data in a `recyclerView` see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)

Comment: You can find the easiest answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66026703/12649010